# Unit test for a sub-method which called from main method and include http-request authoraztion

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocking, mocha.js

I faced to a really complicated scenario, hope you guys give me a hint.

So I have a main method, which is a api endpoint, this method call another method to check if  the user is authorized to use this endpoint or not. 
The sub-endpoint which I called it apiAuthorazation send a get request to a thirdparty url, and this third-party return a response which says this user is authorized, or not!

So I already have a unit test for the main method, but now I want add this authorization part to it. I know I can use muck libs like [Nock](https://scotch.io/tutorials/nodejs-tests-mocking-http-requests) or other similar libraries, but my problem is how can I add this sub-method to my uit test.

This is my api endpoint method :

```
module.exports.api = (event, context, callback) => {
     // Authorization
     let getBearertoken = event.headers.Authorization.replace("Bearer ", '');
     let isAuhtorized = utilities.apiAuthorazation(getBearertoken);
     //Some other Codes
}
```

As you can see I passed a bearer token to my sub-method, and apiAuthorazation method will going to send this token to a third-party api, and  the method is like this :

```
module.exports.apiAuthorazation = function (token){
    let url = process.env.authApiUrl 
    requestLib(`${url}/${token}`, function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) console.log('Error while checking token :', error);
        if(response.isValidUser){
           return true;
        }
        else{
           return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Now my question is how can I include this sub-method to my main method unit test. I use mocha and chai for unit testing, bceause the berear token will expire soon, so when I run the test, I send a sample event which have the berear token in it, but it's already expired, so its kind of useless.

Comment: if you write separate tests for apiAuthorazation(), you can mock it for the tests of your api endpoint. As for the apiAuthoratzation() tests - it depends what you want to test and what this function does. If it is a unit test you can mock out the third party api and let it return any response you like (if you are interested in the other logic of this function). If it is an integration test and you are interested in the real answer of the third party service then you will have to create a fresh token before sending it. In any case: is your question about how to test api() or apiAuthorazation()?

Comment: @Rhayene Actually I want test api but this api will call another method inside the code which call the apiAuthoratzation(), I can write test case for apiAuthoratzation itself and mock it, thats not a problem, my problem is write now the current test write for api, and now that I add this authorization part of it, I really cant figure this out how can I test the sub-method inside the api.

Answer (score 1):

When you unit test Api, you can mock apiAuthorization for the two scenarios (true or false) and test if Api behaves as expected. Dont worry about what happens inside the sub method at all for the Api tests as you are testing Api here and the focus is not on what is happening inside the sub method, apiAuthorization.